# How to fill section on titlesec

Tags: titlesec

How can i make a titleformat that fills in the whole line?
Something like that:

«counter» «name» « ------ rule fill --------»

Normal text....

I managed to do it using the runin type but it has several problems:

> \newcommand{\crulefill}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex
>   depth\dimexpr 0.5pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern 0pt}
>
> \titleformat{\section}[runin] {\bfseries\Large}
>   {\fboxrule=0.5pt\fcolorbox{black}{white!0}{{\color{black}\thesection.}}\rule[.7ex]{10pt}{.5pt}\
>   } {0pt} {\upshape\bfseries\Large} [\
>   \crulefill\vspace*{1.5ex}~\\hspace*{6pt}]

1. \vspace defines the separation between the normal text and the section.
2. \hspace defines the separation in the first line of the normal text (the indentation)
3. When there is no text between a section and a subsection, the space is too large, but when there is text, the space is fine.

[image: Note the space between 1.1 and 1.1.1 when there is no text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with the default `hang` style,and the `explicit` option:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\crulefill}{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 0.7ex depth\dimexpr 0.5pt-0.7ex\hfill\kern 0pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large} {\fboxrule=0.5pt\fcolorbox{black}{white!0}{{\color{black}\thesection.}}\rule[.7ex]{10pt}{.5pt} } {0pt} {\upshape\bfseries\Large#1 \ \crulefill}%

\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries\large} {\thesubsection.\enspace\color{LightSteelBlue}\vrule}{0.6em} {#1}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\section{Sección}

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[11]
\section{Sección}
\lipsum[12]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\color{LightSteelBlue}\vrule\color{black}` should be `{\color{LightSteelBlue}\vrule}`

Comment: @egreg: That's right. I thought I had to revert to the default colour, but you're right. I've changed the code. Thanks for the tip!