# Continuing to enumerate when using "titlesec" package

Tags: sectioning, enumerate, titlesec, unnumbered-sections

I must use the package `\usepackage{titlesec}`.

I have no problem with chapters and sections. However, when using `\subsection{..}`, the enumeration disappears.

**Problem:** My problem is that I want to have numbered subsections, but TexStudio show up unnumbered subsections in my document

**Question:** How to continue to have the subsection enumeration??

Following the code and the image of the pdf.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[explicit,clearempty,nobottomtitles*]{titlesec} % pretty titles
%\usepackage{titlesec} % pretty titles
\usepackage{graphicx}  % \resizebox
\usepackage{xcolor}    % \color, \textcolor
\usepackage{colortbl}  % \cellcolor
\providecommand\phantomsection{}  % just in case we're not using hyperref

% chapter style
\definecolor{chapcolor}{rgb}{0.33,0.73,0}
\newlength\Chapmargin  \Chapmargin=10pt % extra margin at left of chapter title
\newlength\Chaplineext \Chaplineext=1.5in % extension of "hanging" bottom line


% section style
\newsavebox\Secbox % used to temporarily store the section label
\titleformat{\section}%
[hang]{}{}{0pt}%
{%
    \sbox\Secbox{% temporarily save section label in order to measure it later
        %~ \color{white}\bfseries\rmfamily\LARGE\textsuperscript\S\,\thesection% section number, in white over color, bold, roman, LARGE
        \color{white}\bfseries\rmfamily\LARGE\thesection% section number, in white over color, bold, roman, LARGE
    }%
    \def\arraystretch{2}% better vertical margins (for this table only)
    \arrayrulewidth=1pt% thicker lines (for this table only)
    \begin{tabular}{cl@{}}% no margin at the end
        \arrayrulecolor{chapcolor}% colored lines (for this table only)
        \hline%
        \hfill\cellcolor{chapcolor}\usebox\Secbox%
        &%
        \textcolor{chapcolor}{% needs to be outside of the parbox (and use \textcolor) or else it messes up line formatting
            \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd\Secbox-3\tabcolsep\relax}{%
                \raggedright% no stretching/hyphenation
                \LARGE\rmfamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase{#1}% chapter title (roman, bold, uppercase)
            }}%
            \\%
        \end{tabular}%
    }

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{first Section}

\subsection{First Sub Section}

\subsubsection{First SubSub Section}

\subsection{Second Sub Section}

\end{document}
```

**What I obtain:**

[image]

**and what I would like to obtain:**

[image]

Please note that the last figure was obtained by deleting `\usepackage{titlesec}`

Comment: Your problem is that you want to have numbered subsections, but they show up unnumbered in your document?

Comment: yes! even with the code in this answer here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442101/how-to-fill-section-on-titlesec) my laptop continue to give me pdf with NO numbering. Can be something like the new version of `titlesec`?

Comment: If I compile your example, the output document has numbered subsections. Is your installation up-to-date?

Comment: today I have just re-installed texstudio and texlive-full. And I have this problem that I can resolve. My version should be the last one, right? yours can be older

Comment: I would guess you have a very old installation and this old 2016 bug https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15

Comment: your log should show `Package: titlesec 2019/10/16 v2.13 Sectioning titles`

Comment: how to update it?

Comment: Done, problem solved. I have just posted the solution found thaks to your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, it was clear that I face an OLD bug of `titlesec`. The problem is solved with the new version. For more information see the question and the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299969/titlesec-loss-of-section-numbering-with-the-new-update-2016-03-15).

**FOR SOLVING THE BUG**:

Download the right (no buggy) `.sty` and substitute the old one.

**For Ubuntu 18.04 with texlive:**

`sudo wget http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.sty -O /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty`

**For other Linux distros:**

First, run `locate /titlesec.sty` then adapt the previous code.

Comment: directly writing the files to the managed directories is very fragile and could get over-written at any update. Which texllive are you running is there really not a newer version available via the standard apt update mechanisms?

Comment: texliveonfly 1.2 and texstudio 2.12.14

Comment: Old and short lived (just a few days, because I fixed quickly). The odd thing is some Linux distributions included the buggy version for months.